# Flash content not always loading - Win 7 - IE9 & Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, flash, internet-explorer-9

I have a Sony Vaio running Windows 7. YouTube and most flash sites work, but there are a few that have odd behaviors. When the page veja.abril.com.br is loaded, halfway down there are some flash-based new feeds that load. Two of them are getting Spinning Gears.

I have tried disabling and enabling the Chrome flash and the Windows 7 flash in different combinations to no avail.

The symptom is identical in Chrome and IE9.

I have run all updates and installed newest versions of Flash.

I have disabled all the known culprits in IE9 (protected mode etc..)

Still will not load.

- Any thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update your graphics drivers, and if that doesn't resolve the issue, you can then try to [disable hardware acceleration](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are running IE then disable the Chrome Framework BHO (browser helper object) add-in and it should start working.  I have not found a resolution for chrome it seems to have gotten more clunky so I just went back to FF.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing problems with Adobe Flash if the version is higher than 11.1.102.63 and the OS is Windows 7 x64 and the account is non-admin. See if you can run the [older version](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) for testing. If so, yank Adobe's chain about this issue. Not everyone runs around as administrator.